# Get the location type (e.g. Hotel or Restaurant)

Tags: swift

I want to get the type of place that the user is at, like if they are at a restaurant or at a hotel. I have tried to look into that and no one seems to have an answer. Even when printing the full description of the location it doesn't show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this answer. I just used the Yelp API and it gave me more than enough information. This is what I used...
https://medium.com/@khansaryan/yelp-fusion-api-integration-af50dd186a6e

Answer (score 0):

Apple is providing this:

```
    func getLocationAddress(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
        self.getLocation { locations in
                let place = CLLocation(latitude: locations[0].latitude, longitude: locations[0].longitude)
                CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(place) { placemarks, error in
                    guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                        let errorString = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unexpected Error"
                        print("Unable to reverse geocode the given location. Error: \(errorString)")
                        return
                    }
                    var output: [String] = []
                    let reversedGeoLocation = ReversedGeoLocation(with: placemark)
                    output.append(reversedGeoLocation.formattedAddress)
                    completion(output)
                }

        }

    }
```

Also, you should include MapKit
Here's [a link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/2908779-reversegeocodelocation)!

Comment: It is giving me this error 'value of type MainViewController has no member getLocation' on line 2

Comment: Of course that beside this function, you need another function which returns the latitude and longitude.